# Capturing complete SMS response

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am trying to capture the SMS response for a text response in Mobile Connect.
I have tried to use MSG(0).NOUNS ,did not work and then trying to put a for loop where I want to check Noun(1),Noun(2) etc ,but that's not working as well.

Has anybody successfully retrieved the complete sms response ,not the first  word.

Any help would be appreciated.
code snipper I am working on, if this works I will concatenate the values.

```
%%[ 
VAR @msg,@response,@inbound,@rowcount
//arbitary number to check the first 10 words
SET @rowCount=10

/*Stores the response from the sms*/
For @i = 0 to 10 do
SET @response=[MSG(0).NOUN(@i)]
next @i
]%%
%%=v(@response)=%%
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `MSG(0).NOUNS` to retrieve all nouns in the Mobile Originated (MO) message.

```js
%%[ 
var @response

/*Stores the response from the sms*/
set @response = MSG(0).NOUNS
]%%
%%=v(@response)=%%
```

Comment: Hi Eliiot,Thanks,That's what I tried initially,We are using Mobile Connect and Text Response message and it's generating an error at the time of send stating "There was an error processing your request ",Are there any scenarios where NOUNS would not work?

Comment: Hi that's very odd. Are you saying that `MSG(0).NOUN(0)` returns the first noun but `MSG(0).NOUNS` is not working? I've used `MSG(0).NOUNS` quite extensively and never experienced this issue.

Comment: We are using as part of Mobile Connect  as a text response.Yes tried that few times with error,Now I will remove all code and will only keep MSG(0).NOUNS,Will let you know how it goes .

Comment: The code I have now, which is still not working !
    %%[
var @response
set @response=MSG(0).NOUNS
]%% 
%%=v(@response)=%%